# ActiveAdmin with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, cancancan, devise-token-auth

I have a project using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for authentication. I have installed [Active Admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) following [this](https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html).

When I try to access `localhost:3000/admin` I get `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

However, when I comment `config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!` in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`, `localhost:3000/admin` opens the dashboard page.

My question is why am I not getting the login page for active admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that you need to know when working with both `ActiveAdmin` (AA) and `devise_token_auth`. AA uses:

- `Devise` for authentication
- `:admin` as default namespace

It means that all of your AA resources will have routes under `/admin` e.g. `/admin/posts` and they will be authenticated using `Devise`; not `devise_token_auth`.

In order to avail both types of authentication system, you must use two namespaces: one for AA and one for devise_token_auth.

A common strategy in this scenario would be to define AA routes before devise_token_auth like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # AA routes available at /admin
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  # token auth routes available at /api/v1/auth
  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end

end
```

Here AA is using `:admin_users` and token_auth will use `:users` table. Don't forget to adapt them to your needs.

**Note**: If you ever face trouble with your `ApplicationController` while working with AA and devise_token_auth, please [refer to this link](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#im-having-trouble-using-this-gem-alongside-activeadmin).